# processing survey multi-choise data in R

Tags: r, count, missing-data, frequency-distribution

I need to analyse survey data to get the frequency of a multi question variable. I'm using [this R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/questionr/questionr.pdf)

I understand that I need to use the 'multi.split' function in order to create the variable that I will be working with. but I need to know how I can make it reference answers that are not in the data-set, meaning answers that were a part of the original question but was not selected during the survey and therefor should be displayed with the value 0.

Example:
I have the following passable answers:

```
"red", "blue", "green" and "yellow"
```

and my data is (like in the example):

```
v <- c("red/blue","green","red/green","blue/red")
```

when I run this command:

```
multi.table(multi.split(v))
```

I get the following result:

```
        n     %multi
v.blue  2     50
v.red   3     75
v.green 2     50
```

but I would like to get:

```
         n     %multi
v.blue   2     50
v.red    3     75
v.green  2     50
v.yellow 0      0
```

any ideas on how can I do that?

Comment: If you haven't tried it before, the `memisc` package has useful tools for survey analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this package before but I'll give it a try.

The function `multi-split()` produces a data.frame so if you want to add another column before getting the statistics you could do something like the following:

```
v <- c("red/blue","green","red/green","blue/red")
a <- multi.split(v)
a$v.yellow <-  0
multi.table(a)


## > multi.table(a)
## n %multi
## v.blue   2     50
## v.red    3     75
## v.green  2     50
## v.yellow 0      0
```

**Update**
A more generic version would go something like that.

1.`wanted.data` is a char of column names that you always want in your output.
 2. col.to.add are the columns that were not in the `a` data.frame.
 3. Then assign 0 to the columns that were not present.
 4. Finally order the columns so we always have them in the same order.

```
library(questionr)
v <- c("red/blue","green","red/green","blue/red")
wanted_data <-  c("v.red","v.blue","v.green","v.yellow")

 a <- multi.split(v)
 col.to.add<- wanted_data[!(wanted_data%in% colnames(a) )]
 a[col.to.add] <- 0
 a[,order(colnames(a))]
 multi.table(a)

## > multi.table(a)
## n %multi
## v.blue   2     50
## v.red    3     75
## v.green  2     50
## v.yellow 0      0
```

Comment: is there any way of make it more generic? I need to preserve the labels ordering, so that if my labels are: "red", "blue", "green" and "yellow" 
the columns in the table will be (always): red, blue, green and yellow without regrading to how that data-set was ordered or to which labels were a part of the data-set or not. thanks

Comment: @Shlomi I also haven't used this package, but it sounds like you want an ordered factor. Type `?factor` for more info on those.

Comment: @djj Thanks for the example, what should set the columns order, because I see that in 'wanted_data' the order is: 'red', 'blue', 'green' and 'yellow' and that in the printed result the order is: "blue", "red", "green" and "yellow"

Comment: The column order is in alphabetical order. If you want to do something generic I think that's the best way to go. You can always change the order of the columns for the final table in the end